# Does Google Colab uses local resources too? How can I stop that?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I noticed that whenever I open a Google Colab notebook my system fans go high and all of my 4 cores show huge usage (on my ubuntu laptop). Clearly a lot of JS is running on my system.

However, when I host a Jupiter notebook on another machine and use that from my laptop, all the resource usage is normal.

Q: Is there a way to make Google Colab use minimal resources of my PC?
While google colab is an awesome way to share my code (and ask questions), the sound from fan speed annoys me a lot.

p.s; If this is not th right plac to ask this, kindly let me know where can I ask it?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your Google Colab is running in local runtime. By default, it runs on its own Compute Engine, but you do have the option to alter it.
P.S It could also be Google Chrome simply using too many resources when running Colab. Try Edge or other lesser power-hungry browsers.